# DATEDIF Excel - output incorrect

Tags: excel, datediff

I am attempting to calculate the difference between two dates using Excel's DATEDIF function. When I attempt to do so, I get an incorrect output. [image: I am wanting the difference in days, but the output is way off]

How can I fix this? I am trying to get the difference in days - e.g., 26 days

I tried the formula and was expecting to receive the output of 26 days

Comment: Also, if you want the difference in days, just subtract one from the other; you don't need DATEDIF for that.

Comment: If you want the number of working days then networkdays.intl() will do that and again M4 - H4 seems a better option compared to the substitute option shown - perhaps I just don't like typing :)

Comment: @Rory - I could also simply subtract the two values, however, the output is still incorrect! - 26.01.1900

Comment: "street " date? or start date? Theatrical date?

Comment: Format the cell as General. That date is the number 26.

Comment: @SolarMike - M is the start date, H is the end date. Also, the output comes up incorrect again when I add it to an if statement. E.g., =IF(J4="Premium";NETWORKDAYS.INTL(M4;H4);"no") is equal to 19.01.1900 which is incorrect

Comment: Then it is down to your formatting, the result is not a date, it is a NUMBER - so format the dates cells as dates and the result cell as a number.

Comment: @SolarMike again, thank you! Worked out perfectly. Also, thank you everyone for the help